# Timers window of the ThreadX IAR plugin crashing IAR when a 10th timer is created

Tags: iar, threadx

When debugging in IAR, if we open the Timers window of the ThreadX Debugger Plugin, IAR crashes when the 10th timer is created. Similarly, if we debug for a while (after all of the timers have been initialized), and then open the Timers window, IAR again crashes. No error messages are displayed.

We're trying to debug a potential timer issue and we're using IAR 8.11.3 and the ThreadX C-SPY Debugger Plugin. When I open up the Timers window before starting the debugging, I am able to create 9 threadx timers without any issues. But when I create the 10th timer, IAR crashes. When I debug without the Timers window open, I'm able to create more timers and continue debugging. If I then pause and open the Timers window, IAR crashes.

This appears to be a plugin issue. Any ideas what might be causing this behavior or how to resolve it?

Comment: Sounds like a bug which you should discuss with IAR support. I doubt that there's much we could help you with.